# Random generated array does not print small value correctly

Tags: java, loops

my code is not working because it is always printing small value as 0.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public class Tests {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] num=new int[10];
        Random random= new Random();
        //1st time both big and small value will be at 0
        int big=num[0];
        int small=num[0];

        for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){

            num[i]=random.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(num[i] +" ");

            if(num[i]>big){
                big=num[i];             
            }   
            if(num[i]<small){
                small=num[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Big " + big);
        System.out.println("Small " + small);
    }
}
```

See below the issue: 
Good Result:

5 1 1 3 8 3 5 1 1 0 
Big 8
Small 0

Bad Result:
6 8 8 1 7 5 2 6 8 4 
Big 8
Small 0

Comment: since 0 is smaller than 1 to 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `small` is 0 and every random value will be generated between 0 and 10, so 0 is the smallest.

To fix it, change to

```
int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you initiated the int array `int [] num=new int[10];` it assigned `zero(0)` to all index.

So, when you let `int small=num[0];` it contain **zero(0)**

So, whatever the value are coming, following block always comparing `small` as zero(0). So, not changing the `small` variable!

```
if(num[i]<small){
   small=num[i];
}
```

assign `int small=Integer.MAX_VALUE;` AND `int big=Integer.MIN_VALUE;` then it will all work!

Answer (score 1):

Declare `int small` as:

```
int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

And now it will work.

Note: And also it is better to declare `int big` as

```
int big = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

init array in another loop. when you init int array all of them are 0.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = new int[10];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
            num[i] = random.nextInt(10);
        }
        //1st time both big and small value will be at 0
        int big = num[0];
        int small = num[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i] + " ");

            if (num[i] > big) {
                big = num[i];
            }
            if (num[i] < small) {
                small = num[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Big " + big);
        System.out.println("Small " + small);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `int [] num=new int[10];` , `num` array will be initialized with 0 for all 10 places i.e. num[0]= 0, num[1]=0...

and so as suggested by others use `int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Always remember, when you initialize something to a variable which stores the biggest, initialize a small value like 0 and for a small variable initialize it with the biggest number possible.